# Vue.js route params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I saw a line of code in a project that I just started working on. So, I am kind of new to Vue.js. The code is as below:

```
 routes: [{
    path: '/coursePage/:contentId/:title?',
    name: 'coursePage',
    component: coursePage,
    meta: {requireAuth: false}
  },
```

The route param - contentId works fine but I can't figure out the purpose of ? in param - title?
Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last `?` means this parameter is optional.

The `vue-router` will not complain if you do not pass this parameter while building the dynamic route.

You can do

```
this.$router.push({
    name: coursePage,
    params: { contentId: 1 }
})
```

or

```
this.$router.push({
    name: coursePage,
    params: { contentId: 1, title: 2 }
})
```